# cocoa:How to obtain the View above all button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I want obtain the View above all button,Button to set the background.The following code error
When the program is open,Settings button background.

```
NSButton *button = [(AppWindow *)self.window button];


if (button.tag==5) {
    [button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtnDown.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase; it's impossible to understand what you want.

Comment: When the program is open,Settings button background.

Comment: Try adding a bracket to self.window so it becomes (AppWindow *)(self.window)

Comment: Does your instance of AppWindow have a property called "button"?  If not, then your first line will give you an error because there is no method of NSWindow called "button"